# Is “be headed to from here“ grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence ’As for intellectuals, they should be aware of the world is headed to from here, and work together to facilitate reason to prevail over anti-reason.’

Whether the preposition ’to’ in the phrase ‘headed to’ should be deleted or not?

Comment: You have to be headed to a place, so it should be _where the world is headed to_.

Comment: Your sentence does not seem to have been written by a native speaker. "Where" (see Kate Bunting above) is required and so is "to". To is similar to "towards". -> they should be aware of **where** the world is headed to -> they should be aware of **the place *to* which** the world is headed.**

Answer (score 0):

If you head a department, company, or organization, you are the person in charge of it.

So, “...the world is headed...” is the passive voice. Here it’s necessary to omit To

But, if you want say ‘go’ or travel towards. You can use ‘To’ in your example.